# Retrieve android's OS country list

Tags: clock, utc, gmt, city, countries

I am writing an alarm Clock application in android, and I wonder if there is any single way to retrieve android os's countries and cities list along with the GMT setting or can I use native app's setting so that my application work without getting connected to the internet as alarm clock (default android app) does.

Answer (score 0):

On [citytimezones](http://www.citytimezones.info/) you can download a list of cities and their respective timezone on CSV/TSV format.

Here is a small snippet of the list

```
"Aalborg","(GMT+01:00) Brussels, Copenhagen, Madrid, Paris","Denmark",57.02888870239258,9.917778015136719,"Romance Standard Time"
"Abbotsford, BC","(GMT-08:00) Pacific Time (US & Canada); Tijuana","Canada",49.06638717651367,-122.30000305175781,"Pacific Standard Time"
"Aberdeen","(GMT) Dublin, Edinburgh, Lisbon, London","United Kingdom",57.150001525878906,-2.0999999046325684,"GMT Standard Time"
"Abidjan","(GMT) Greenwich Mean Time","Cote d'Ivoire",5.336389064788818,-4.027777671813965,"Greenwich Standard Time"
"Abu Dhabi","(GMT+04:00) Abu Dhabi, Muscat","United Arab Emirates",24.483333587646484,54.36666488647461,"Arabian Standard Time"
```

Comment: thanks, but i am afraid i need country images as well along with this information. :(

Comment: when i asked that question it wasn't a requirement. Sorry for bothering you :(